# Writing map of data to XML according to a format which is user-defined

Tags: java, xml

I need to write a map of string data to an XML document. The XML document has a specific format. An entry key determines where in the XML document the value will be written to. See below for an example (pseudo-code where appropriate);

```
map = {"document_id": "123"; "document_type": "type_A"}
```

Produces an XML file like this;

```
<document>
    <document_id>123</document_id>
    <document_type>type_A</document_type>
</document>
```

I need the format of the target XML document (and where the map data is written to in it) to be user-configurable. For example;

```
<node name="document">
    <node name="document_id">${document_id}</node>
    <node name="document_type">${document_type}</node>
</node>
```

I feel like my proposed solution would be complex and a re-invention of the wheel. I figure there must be some established way to do this but after searching the internet I can't seem to find it. Can anyone offer suggestions on how I may achieve what I want to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

have you looked into using an XSLT file for transforming the information?

I imagine that you could take the Data entered into a form and create a new XML file and then use an XSLT file to format it to the right XML format and insert it into your target XML.

I think this is kind of what you are looking for if i read the question correctly

Comment: glad that I could help